# Yii Framework/PDO getting error CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, pdo, yii

I'm trying to insert some data into a table using the Yii Framework together with the PDO object and get the following error

I'm building the query using this code

```
$connection = CActiveRecord::getDbConnection();

        $sql="INSERT INTO sms_logs (to, from, message,error_code,date_send) VALUES (:to,:from,:message,:error_code,:date_send)";
        $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
        $command->bindParam(":to",$to,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $command->bindParam(":from",$from,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $command->bindParam(":message",$message,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $command->bindParam(":error_code",$code,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $command->bindParam(":date_send",date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $command->execute();
```

And then as soon as I run the code I get

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to, from, message,error_code,date_send) VALUES ('27724963345','27723663542','Hap' at line 1INSERT INTO sms_logs (to, from, message,error_code,date_send) VALUES (:to,:from,:message,:error_code,:date_send)
```

any suggestions will be welcome! using mySql as the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the word `from` in your $sql. It is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I overlooked the reserved words, problem solved ;-)

Comment: Glad that sorted it. Don't forget about the `CProfileLogRoute` log route. It shows you exactly what queries are being run, which can help in tracking down problems.