# MySQL Syntax with DELETE FROM?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this bit of `SQL` that always returns an error, though I can't find why it is returning the error. I have connected to the database with no errors. I'm running `PHP 5.2.17`, `MySQL 5.5.25a`, and `Apache 2.4.2.`

The `SQL`:

```
DELETE FROM mail WHERE to=1
```

The error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'to=1' at line 1

Comment: Dupe of [Yii Framework/PDO getting error CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE\[42000\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2316616/), [SQLSTATE\[42000\]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4544051/) and others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TO` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you need to use backticks:

```
 DELETE FROM mail WHERE `to` = 1
```

Comment: you should be able to see it as it is highlighted :)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I didn't know it was reserved xD I was running it from a PHP file, so the query was enclosed in quotations.

Comment: It's a good habit to use backticks anyways, and quote your values (which I didn't do in the example). The query actually isn't executed with quotations, that's just PHP syntax. You may click the checkmark to the left to mark your question as resolved if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `backticks` on the column name escapes in from **[MySQL Reserved Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**

```
DELETE FROM mail WHERE `to`=1
```

Answer (score -1):

if the column to is not e.g. INT or DEC you should make it `to = "1"`